# Cannot convert return expression of type 'NSFetchedResultsController' to return type 'NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>'

Tags: swift, xcode, return

I'm trying to convert a bit of code from swift 2 to swift 3 and everything has been going fine until I get to this section of code:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>{
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
```

Xcode brings up the error:

```
    Cannot convert return expression of type 'NSFetchedResultsController' to return type
   'NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>'
```

And i'm a bit stumped on how to fix it

Comment: Which line of code displays the error? Could you also provide the line of code that declares  `_fetchedResultsController`

Comment: the line of code that the error shows up on is  'return _fetchedResultsController!'